# How do I write the STRUCT for a hashtable in x86 MASM Assembly language?

Tags: assembly, hashtable, masm

```
Include irvine32.inc

.data
    HTEntry STRUCT
    key BYTE PTR ?   ; Pointer to a null-terminated string  
    value BYTE PTR ?  ; Pointer to a null-terminated string  
    next BYTE PTR ?    ; Pointer to the next entry in the bucket  
    HTEntry ENDS  

    HashTable STRUCT  
    hashsize DWORD ?              ; Current size of the hash table  
    maxLoadFactor DWORD ?         ; Maximum load factor before resizing  
    buckets DWORD PTR : DWORD ? ; Array of bucket pointers  
    HashTable ENDS
```

```
I get the following errors:
(For reference line 5 starts with key)
    hash.asm(5): error A2009: syntax error in expression
    hash.asm(6): error A2009: syntax error in expression
    hash.asm(7): error A2009: syntax error in expression
    hash.asm(13): error A2009: syntax error in expression
```

I'm expecting to initialize a sturcture for a hashtable. I tried switching position of ptr and byte and playing with syntax to no avail.

Comment: Regardless of a struct or not, a pointer-sized object in static storage is done with `DWORD ?` (or QWORD ?) in 64-bit code).  The assembler doesn't care whether you're going to use it as a pointer, especially not what type it points to.  (x86 doesn't have memory-indirect addressing, so even MASM's magical implicit operand-size of named "variables" in memory doesn't come into play.)

Answer (score 0):

Like @PeterCordes said, the data section doesn't really understand types beyond `byte`, `word`, `dword`, `qword`, etc., because to be honest, neither does the CPU. It doesn't actually know what's a pointer and what isn't, that's the programmer's job, which is why in assembly you can attempt to dereference anything as if it were a pointer. This is how you should write your data section.

```
.data
    HTEntry STRUCT
    key DWORD ?   ; Pointer to a null-terminated string  
    value DWORD ?  ; Pointer to a null-terminated string  
    next DWORD ?    ; Pointer to the next entry in the bucket  
    HTEntry ENDS  

    HashTable STRUCT  
    hashsize DWORD ?              ; Current size of the hash table  
    maxLoadFactor DWORD ?         ; Maximum load factor before resizing  
    buckets DWORD ? ; Array of bucket pointers  
    HashTable ENDS
```

Then in your code section if you want to actually do some reading from memory:

```
mov al, BYTE PTR [key] 
;I can't remember if the brackets go around "byte ptr" or not, please forgive me
```

Comment: MASM [understands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/masm/typedef-masm?view=msvc-170) `typedef`, so you could do `POINTER TYPEDEF DWORD`, which would not only help highlight what elements are pointers (aka self-documenting), it allows you to easily switch to QWORD if you decide to switch to x64.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd That's an excellent suggestion, I'll definitely start doing that.